# Execute a command if new line is found in script output

Tags: android, bash, shell, grep, logcat

I am having huge difficulties writing a simple bash script.

I basically want to monitor a debug log 24/7 and listen for a new line. If there is a new line I want it to execute a command.

```
logcat | grep com.amazon.firelauncher/.Launcher
```

When I run this code, I get a live debug window, I want to execute a command (reboot for an example) whenever a new line pops up in that command.

How can this be done? I tried sending the output to a file and monitoring that file for filesize change, but it does not work. I really need assistance!

Comment: OS X/Linux? And if Linux, what distribution? Or is this bash running inside of an Android phone?

Comment: This is bash running on android with busybox, so it has the capabilities of android. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The command:
am monitor | grep firelauncher
works better, and whenever the output:   
** Activity starting: com.amazon.firelauncher
is shown, I would like to execute a command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `read` for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while logcat | grep "com.amazon.firelauncher/.Launcher" | read -r line; do
    echo "Text read from logcat"
    /path/to/executable
done
```

Comment: I love you, this is actually working! I will +1 you as soon as I can!

Comment: You should be proud of yourself, this is actually a really big problem around the internet, I read many people's attempts and only you were successful.

Answer (score 0):

This was my final answer, but I would not have concluded it if it was not for the help of Martin Konecny, he did all the heavy lifting.

```
#!/bin/bash
am monitor | while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == *"firelauncher"* ]]
    then
      am start com.newlauncher.launcher
    fi
done
```